# Apple script subfolder with name with space

Tags: unix, applescript

I use apple script to create subfolders in the current directory.
When the subfolder name is more than one word the script creates a separate subfolder for each word. In unix the \ indicates a space between words. But when use it in the script I get alert syntax error Expected “"” but found unknown token.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROZXM.png)

```
tell application "Finder"
    set sel to item 1 of (get selection)
    if class of sel is folder then
        set currentDir to sel as text
    else
        set currentDir to (container of sel) as text
    end if
end tell
do shell script "cd " & (quoted form of POSIX path of currentDir) & "; mkdir CLR\ GRD"
do shell script "cd " & (quoted form of POSIX path of currentDir) & "; mkdir RETOUCHED"
do shell script "cd " & (quoted form of POSIX path of currentDir) & "; mkdir WIP"
do shell script "cd " & (quoted form of POSIX path of currentDir) & "; mkdir TRASH"
```

Answer (score 0):

In a `do shell script` line a backslash in a literal string must be escaped with a second backslash

```
do shell script "cd " & (quoted form of POSIX path of currentDir) & "; mkdir CLR\\ GRD"
```

There is a more convenient form to create the subfolders

```
tell application "Finder"
    set sel to item 1 of (get selection)
    if class of sel is folder then
        set currentDir to sel as text
    else
        set currentDir to (container of sel) as text
    end if
end tell
do shell script "mkdir -p " & (quoted form of POSIX path of currentDir) & "{'CLR GRD',RETOUCHED,WIP,TRASH}"
```